# SWIFT 3: List with Dropdown pictures/clips

Tags: swift, list, dropdown

I'm trying to develop an app that has a similar look as the pictures that I have attached here, since I really like that Idea.

[image]

After selecting an item, it drops down and a clip starts playing

Any idea on how to implement this? I can work with tables and lists, but I have no idea on how to actually implement something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with multiple ways

1. let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: YourSelectedRow, inSection: 0)

   ```
     tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPath, withRowAnimation: .none )

        insert a different row here which will be tricky to manage.
   ```
2. Create all this headers and and create only one cell under selected section.

   ```
    var selectedSection =  -1 

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
      {
            let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 50)
            let button = UIButton(frame: view.frame)
            button.tag = section
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectExercise(_:), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
      }

     func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
      {
           return 5 
      }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
       {
           if section == selectedSection
            {
               return 1
         }
        else
           {
               return 0
        }
       }

         func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        {
                   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(“YourDetailCell”, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourDetailCell
           return cell
     }

    fun selectExercise(sender:UIButton)
       {
       selectedSection = sender.tag 
       }
   ```
3. Create two cells and change that  specific cell with whole cell portion with animation

   ```
   var selectedRow =  -1 

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
           if selectedRow == -1
        {
                selectedRow = indexPath.row 
                tblConfirmedServices.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
         }
           else
        {
               selectedRow = - 1 
            tblConfirmedServices.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathPre], withRowAnimation: .Top)
       }       
     }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
      {
       if selectedRow = indexPath.row
        {
                   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(“YourDetailCell”, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourDetailCell
               return cell
        }
        else
        {
               let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(“YourCell”, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourCell
               return cell
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: Personally, I would say option 2 is the "most correct" according to the way it's *supposed* to work.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to experiment with this!